# Angular js form submit

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs.
   Currently i have code like this that submits the form on button click

```
<form ng-submit="reloadA(resultsPerPage)">
    <select ng-model="resultsPerPage">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    </select>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I need that form should be submitted on selecting the option without need of the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, for this you should have that `ng-submit` function in the select, like this;

```
<form>
   <select ng-change="reloadA(resultsPerPage)" ng-model="resultsPerPage">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! saved the day :)

Comment: ok, I see. thanks man, I also just learnt this one or two weeks ago; also an angularjs noob :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `ng-change` here

```
<select ng-model="resultsPerPage" ng-change="reloadA(resultsPerPage)">
```

Comment: damn you I was first!

Comment: +10 in the spirit of sportsmanship, they're basically the same answer anyways. . .now if i can just get that sportsmanship badge...